# Keycloak invoking rest -> response unauthorized

Tags: java, rest, keycloak

I have a question regarding keycloak. I have the setup Keycloak standalone, wildfly with keycloak adapter and want to access a rest point of my service deployed in wildfly which is secured by keycloak. Rest without keycloaksecurity is working fine. But when I want to access the secured endpoint, I always get an unauthorized response.
My Client (JavaFX) is obtaining the access token just fine, I get an exception unauthorized if I enter wrong credentials. So the error should be when invoking the restpoint, am I wrong? The critical code of my task to access the Rest Point is 
    `Client client = ResteasyClientBuilder.newClient();
                try {
                    final Response response =
                            client.target(getTarget())
                                    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                    .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + getUserSession().getAccessToken().getToken()).buildGet().invoke();
...(read response throw exceptions etc)`

I have created a KeyclaokClient for the war file and the JavaFX Client. The keycloak.json lies in the folder WEB-INF of my war file and in the resources folder of my JavaFX Client respectively.
My question is, if I am invoking the restpoint and setting the header correctly or not...since the respoint, when not secured, works just fine I am unsure what else in code I should post.

Comment: Should not there be a space after "Bearer"?

Comment: there is just a copy paste error

Answer (score 0):

Problem was configuration of keycloak. I had https://localhost:PORT as auth server but it was expecting http://localhost:PORT